Parameter 'servers' Connection Problem Cross Platform
How can we solve this problem

"System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'List of configured name servers must not be empty. (Parameter 'servers')'"

I tried test connection our Collections but I couldn't:
const string connectionUri = "mongodb+srv://<*****>:<******>@cluster0.jggom.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=Cluster0";

var settings = MongoClientSettings.FromConnectionString(connectionUri);
// Set the ServerApi field of the settings object to set the version of the Stable API on the client
settings.ServerApi = new ServerApi(ServerApiVersion.V1);

I used this way but it's showed timeout problem:
 const string connectionUri = "**mongodb:/**/<*****>:<******>@cluster0.jggom.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=Cluster0";



The connection string started with **mongodb:/ is invalid. So I doubt it can work in any case. 2. it's showed timeout problem - provide the full error. 3. "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'List of configured name servers must not be empty. (Parameter 'servers')'" - the provided connection string can't trigger this error. Please clarify your question and add more details

